# Conversion of Data frame consisting of a timestamp of UTC to Indian Standard time in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, data-science

I wan to convert the given set of data present in the data frame of timestamp currently in the UTC format to be converted to Indian Standard Time.

Given below is the type of data taken in a Data frame:-

Time Series
0   01-02-2018 16:23:07
1   01-02-2018 16:23:08
2   01-02-2018 16:23:09
3   01-02-2018 16:23:10
4   01-02-2018 16:23:11

Given below is my code:

```
enter code here
import pandas as pd
load_var=pd.read_excel(r'path/file_name.xlsx')
load_var
a=load_var[['Time Series']]
a
```

Please suggest the next steps in the code to convert the UTC to IST

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First convert the column to date-timestamp-format-type if it's not converted

```
import dateutil
...
# Converting to date-type (if it's already in that format)
load_var['Time Series'] = load_var['Time Series'].apply(dateutil.parser.parse)

#Then use `tz_localize` to make timestamps aware about time zone and then convert to IST (Asia/Kolkata)
load_var['Time Series_ist'] = pd.to_datetime(load_var['Time Series']).\
                                               dt.tz_localize('utc').\
                                               dt.tz_convert('Asia/Kolkata')
```